# how can i show the title only in toolbar not in open collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, xml

When I using the `collapsing Toolbar` every Thing is `ok` but , I have a little problem with title of collapsing toolbar , i just want show the title when collapsing toolbar is closed , not when it's open :

[image]

This is my xml where i add the collapsing toolbar :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/aks"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="سلام"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set it programmatically like this may be this work.

```
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("WhiteBoard");
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.transperent));
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: @majid look my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your sulutuion but it's not work and title still show.

Comment: Thanks my friend it's work nice and exactly what i want

Comment: @majid glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout 
    app:titleEnabled="false">
</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Put that in your CollapsingToolbarLayout